# OpenCV converts HSL to RGB

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, hsl

I am using OpenCV python to convert a single HSL value to RGB value.

Since there is no HSL2RGB flag, so I used HLS2RGB flag. I assumed HSL and HLS refers to the same color space but just flipping the S and L values. Is that right?

So here is my attempt:

```
import cv2

hls = (0, 50, 100)  # This is color Red
rgb = cv2.cvtColor( np.uint8([[hls]] ), cv2.COLOR_HLS2RGB)[0][0]
```

After conversion, `rgb` value is [70, 30, 30]

However, when I checked this RGB value on online RGB picker, the color is dark brown.

Any idea where could go wrong in the conversion? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be `hls = (0, 128, 255)`? An `uint8` matrix goes up to 256, not 100.

Comment: @Thomas Ah thank you so much, so the HSL value is based on percentage, and not the absolute value? It seems that the S:100 is expanded to its max 255 (if started index 0), and the L: ceil(50% * 255) = 128. Is this the right way retrieving the values?

Comment: I tried this method on converting Green HLS (120, 33%, 100%) to RGB, and the H value is a degree out of 360, so 120/360 * 255 = 85. L is a percentage, so ceil(0.33 * 255) =  85, and S is also a percentage, so it's simply 255. HLS value in uint8 is thus (85, 85, 255). However, the RGB converted from this HLS is (0,170,142), different from the expected RGB (0, 168, 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HLS ranges in OpenCV are

```
H -> 0 - 180
L -> 0 - 255
S -> 0 - 255
```

So if the HLS range you are using are

```
H -> 0 - 360
L -> 0 - 100
S -> 0 - 100
```

you have to convert it to OpenCV's range first

```
hls = (0, 50, 100)
hls_conv = (hls[0]/2, hls[1]*2.55, hls[2]*2.55)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8([[hls_conv]]), cv2.COLOR_HLS2RGB)[0][0]
```

which will result in rgb being [254, 0, 0]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the HLS range of the OpenCV! This makes the solution crystal clear now. I will mark your answer as the solution. Thank you for your great explanation.